# How to make right sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and I want in one query take few values.

Tables:

```
users
|user_id  |
|name     |

user_group_link
|user_id  |
|group_id |
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT users.*, user_group_link.* 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_group_link ON users.user_id = user_group_link.user_id 
WHERE user_group_link.group_id = 10 
AND user_group_link.group_id = 11
AND user_group_link.group_id = 12
```

Problem is that AND doesnt work. I don't understand why it does not work cause i used and before and it seemed to work

Comment: The group_id cannot be 10,11 and 12 at a time for one record; so you will not get any result. Try to use OR

Comment: there was not errors. it just return empty fields

Comment: thank U. Next time i will organize my tables like that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with this query: there is not a single row that has 10, 11 **AND** 12 as group_id... you need **OR** here!

```
SELECT users.*, user_group_link.* 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_group_link ON users.user_id = user_group_link.user_id 
WHERE user_group_link.group_id = 10 
OR user_group_link.group_id = 11
OR user_group_link.group_id = 12
```

Alternative:

```
SELECT users.*, user_group_link.* 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_group_link ON users.user_id = user_group_link.user_id 
WHERE user_group_link.group_id IN (10,11,12)
```

Answer (score 3):

`user_group_link.group_id` can't be `10`, `11`, or `12` **at the same time**, you need `OR` instead of `AND`.

So your query should be:

```
SELECT users.*, user_group_link.* 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_group_link ON users.user_id = user_group_link.user_id 
WHERE user_group_link.group_id = 10 
OR user_group_link.group_id = 11
OR  user_group_link.group_id = 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `IN`

```
  SELECT users.*, user_group_link.* 
  FROM users
  LEFT JOIN user_group_link ON users.user_id = user_group_link.user_id 
  WHERE user_group_link.group_id IN ('10','11','12')
```